# How do I assign a custom post to all terms in a custom taxonomy?

Tags: terms, bulk

I'm building a database of cities as a part of a "location" taxonomy. In order for the terms to render, as far as I've found, they need to have some type of content associated with them. My work-around is to create a "placeholder" post, assign it to the respective terms, then move it to the trash.

So, first, if you have any suggestions for a *better* way to get the terms to display *without* yet having content associated with them, please let me know!

Otherwise, what's the best way to bulk assign terms to a custom post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With functions like get_terms, there is an argument hide_empty that will allow terms without associated posts to be shown. Set hide_empty to 0 and you will see your terms.

Comment: I was having the problem with actual displaying the term pages - not generating a list. It turned out to not be an issue, though - if I recall correctly I just had to reset my permalinks. Thank you for your answer.